# VSCode Django HTML Formatting Issues

Tags: visual-studio-code, django-templates, formatting

Scouring the web and SO as well and it seems like people used to be able to get things working with Beautify, which is now **deprecated**, so I have had no luck getting this to work in **2024**.

Here is the code *formatted the way I want*:

```
{% load static cms_tags %}
<div class="list-item">
  {% if instance.image_src %}
  <img class="lazy" src="{{ instance.image_src.url }}" alt="{% if instance.image_alt %}{{ instance.image_alt }}{% endif %} " />
  {% endif %} {% if instance.image_caption %}
  <label class="{% if instance.small_caption %}small{% endif %}">{{ instance.image_caption }}</label>
  {% endif %} {% if instance.image_description %}
  <p>{{ instance.image_description }}</p>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

I would not even have an issue if it were formatted like this:

```
{% load static cms_tags %}
<div class="list-item">
  {% if instance.image_src %}
    <img class="lazy" src="{{ instance.image_src.url }}" alt="{% if instance.image_alt %}{{ instance.image_alt }}{% endif %} " />
  {% endif %}
  {% if instance.image_caption %}
    <label class="{% if instance.small_caption %}small{% endif %}">{{ instance.image_caption }}</label>
  {% endif %}
  {% if instance.image_description %}
    <p>{{ instance.image_description }}</p>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

When I Save it or move to another file it gets reformatted like the following. It seems to be wrapping way before my threshold of 250 characters. It seems to not even be using the `"html.format.wrapAttributes": "aligned-multiple"` setting which would at least leave the first attribute on the same line and then stack them vertically.

```
{% load static cms_tags %}
<div class="list-item">
  {% if instance.image_src %}
  <img
    class="lazy"
    src="{{ instance.image_src.url }}"
    alt="{% if instance.image_alt %}{{ instance.image_alt }}{% endif %} "
  />
  {% endif %} {% if instance.image_caption %}
  <label class="{% if instance.small_caption %}small{% endif %}"
    >{{ instance.image_caption }}</label
  >
  {% endif %} {% if instance.image_description %}
  <p>{{ instance.image_description }}</p>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Here is my `settings.json` file:

```
{
  "files.associations": {
    "**/templates/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements",
    "*.html": "html"
  },
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "django-html": "html",
    "vue-html": "html",
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "workbench.colorTheme": "One Monokai",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
  "editor.linkedEditing": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "eslint.run": "onSave",
  "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
  "editor.wordWrapColumn": 250,
  "editor.wrappingIndent": "same",
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.insertSpaces": false,
  "prettier.useTabs": true,
  "debug.console.wordWrap": false,
  "prettier.printWidth": 250,
  "prettier.singleAttributePerLine": false,
  "html.format.wrapLineLength": 250,
  "html.format.wrapAttributes": "aligned-multiple",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions": {
    "js-beautify-html": {
      "wrap_attributes": "force-expand-multiline"
    },
    "prettyhtml": {
      "printWidth": 250,
      "singleQuote": false,
      "wrapAttributes": false,
      "sortAttributes": false
    }
  },
  "[html]": {
    "editor.wordWrap": "off"
  },
  "[django-html]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "batisteo.vscode-django",
    "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 250,
    "editor.wrappingIndent": "same",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.insertSpaces": false
  },
  "editor.guides.bracketPairs": true
}
```

Allegedly, the `[django-html]` section should have fixed it, but it does not. Each time, I make a change to this file, I restart VSCode, nothing is working.